# IP Address Shows Instead of Custom Domain Name (Apache)

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I can successfully visit my website hosted on a VPS by entering in the custom domain name I purchased. However, when the site loads in the browser I still see the IP address of my VPS instead of my domain name. I can't quite figure out what I need to do. I've set up both an A Record and a CNAME on my VPS. I have Apache installed. I've tried a number of fixes and I'm not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. It had to do with my installation of Wordpress. Under Settings - General I needed to set my WordPress Address (URL) to my IP and Site Address (URL) to my custom domain name